# Why sometimes reflexive verbs use "sich" and sometime the verb alone?

Tags: verb, reflexive

I was reading reflexive verbs list and I noticed some verbs can be used without reflexive *sich*, for example *sich beeilen*.

I would like to know if there is a rule to it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A reflexive verb always needs a reflexive pronoun. Are you sure those examples contain no declination of "sich", namely "mich"/"mir", "dich"/"dir", "euch" or "uns"?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know *beeilen* must be used with a reflexive pronoun. But, as YetiCGN pointed out, that doesn't have to be *sich* since there are different reflexive pronouns depending on the subject: *sich*, *mich*, *dich*, *uns*, etc. In fact, other than *sich*, the reflexive pronouns look just like regular personal pronouns.

There are many verbs which do have both a transitive form and a reflexive form though. One common way this can occur is when the reflexive form is used to say an action is happening but without mentioning who or what is performing the action. For example the verb *öffnen* is a transitive verb ("to open"):

> *Ich öffne die Tür.* -- "I'm opening the door."

In English you can just omit the subject and "the door" takes over in a kind of passive voice: "The door is opening." The German version requires a reflexive pronoun to accomplish this:

> *Die Tür öffnet sich.* -- "The door is opening."

Note, however, that some German verbs don't need the reflexive pronoun. So:

> *Er bricht den Teller.* --"He's breaking the plate."
> *Der Teller bricht.* -- "The plate is breaking."

I don't know if there's a general rule for telling whether a reflexive pronoun is needed or not for a given verb.

Comment: "Der RDBury bricht sich den Arm"... ;-)